# Uncaught TypeError: x is not a function when Importing Factory Function

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, import

I have a factory function called updateUI which I am importing into index.js. When imported, the instance of updateUI is recognized, however I am given an error when attempting to call updateUI's methods.

Putting all of the code into index.js gets rid of the bug, but it still has me scratching my head. It seems the problem occurs only when importing. Why are the method's not being recognized?

#### index.js

```
import '../../dist/output.css';
import { updateUI } from './display.js';
    
    
const test = updateUI('Daly City');
test.setBackground();
```

#### display.js

```
import { getWeather } from './apiCall';

const updateUI = async(location) => {
    const res = await getWeather(location, process.env.apiKEY);

    function updateCity() {
        const city = document.querySelector('#location');
        city.innerHTML = res.name;
    };

    function updateCurrentTemp() {
        const currentTemp = document.querySelector('#current-temp');
        const farenheit = Math.round((9/5)*(res.main.temp - 273) + 32);
        currentTemp.innerHTML = farenheit;
    };

    function updateConditions() {
        const condition = document.querySelector('#weather');
        condition.innerHTML = res.weather[0].description;
    };

    function setBackground() {
        const date = new Date();
        let time = date.getTime();
        console.log(time);
    };

    return { updateCity, updateCurrentTemp, updateConditions, setBackground }
};

export { updateUI };
```

Comment: Please copy your code here rather than post an image of it. It will make it easier for us to help out.

Comment: @GenericUser updated

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError:`... you missed out the most important part, the error itself! Please include it.

Comment: `updateUI` is asynchronous and returns a promise. You're trying to get the returned value `setBackground()` before it is returned. Use `await` in an `async` function or `.then()`.

Comment: @code Ah I see, I assumed the original async..await in updateUI would "carry over" to index.js. Thank you very much. Still trying to wrap my head around promises.

Comment: It's okay . Asynchronous takes a while to learn, but it'll eventually come along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question answered by @code in the comments.